# SimpleJdbcInsert with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

This is the relevan code I wrote:

```
new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
    .withSchemaName("test")
    .withTableName("tableName")
    .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("idColumn");
```

When I call the `executeAndReturnKey(parameters)` I read this on the console:

> WARN 
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.TableMetaDataProvider:locateTableAndProcessMetaData:336]
>   (main:) Unable to locate table meta data for 'tableName' -- column
>   names must be provided

Why does this happen? I know I can manually specify column names, but it's not the point of using JdbcSimpleInsert, I believe.

- MySQL version is 5.5.9
- MySQL Connector/J 5.1.23
- Spring 3.2.1

Comment: do you have a table called tableName with columns and you can read/write it from sql?

Comment: Sure, in fact if I manually specify, with usingColumns() the columns I'm writing to, the query is correctly generated and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While executing the same query on a different MySQL server, I've came across this error:`java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the given statement`.
So I've killed to birds with a stone :)

So, just add `generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true` to the **JDBC connection URL** and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got an identical error, for a different reason. In my JDBC connection string, I listed the schema. Therefore, putting the `withSchemaName` clause caused this error. When I removed it, the insert worked.